# JavaScript - Load a class through AJAX and instantiate it by extracting the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a two js files.
First one (file A) contains a code that creates a new class by inheriting other class

```
A.js - 
const one = () => {
  someClass.call(this);
  otherClass.call(this);
  this.ownMethod = () => {};
}
```

Second file (file B) has the code where I load the class from file A, through Ajax. Now I need to create an object of that class in file B.

```
 $.ajax({
  url: basePath+"/A.js",
  method: "GET",
  success: function(response) {
  var obj = response;
  // here I need to make an object of the class that was received by ajax
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you provide a little more context, what you're actually trying to achieve? It seems like you want to code some kind of asynchronous JavaScript module loading. There are plenty of tools to achieve this available, for example webpack.

Comment: A.js and B.js are both simple javascript files in the same domain. Basically, I am making an application where pages load asynchronously but each page has different style according to the nature of the data. I am trying to create an object which has the specific properties, by getting a reference from a different file in the same domain.

My problem is that when I run the fetched class function in B.js, it gives me an error saying 'it's not a function'
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have an application where the main screen, B.js, has to load a script A.js asynchronously, in a div. Inside A.js, there is a class, which is inheriting from other classes and overriding a few methods. Now I need the 'this' reference for an object of the class in A.js, to be used in file B.js. 
B.js is loading A.jx through Ajax.

Comment: I want this to happen -
In B.js, I should be able to do
"let obj = new one();"

Comment: That's what I suspected. I would highly recommend you get familiar with webpack, a JavaScript module bundler that lets you split your code into multiple bundles that you can load asynchronously. I don't think what you are trying to achieve can be done with jQuery.

Comment: A very ugly way may be to use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to turn the data string you get from the  Ajax request into executable code. But I wouldn't to that.